# How to center links vertical within div?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble on centering my links vertically. Can anyone tell me how to center my links vertically within the #nav-links div? my layout is here http://deliciousmanga.com/demo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should used table behavior and set your nav-bar container the max height:

```
#nav-links {
    float: right;
    width: 48%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
}
#nav-links ul {
    display: table-cell;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to adjust padding-top: *px on #nav-links

The other way is to make everything in divs, and then just style the div, and write text within the div.
Set position: relative; top: 50; transform: translate(0, -50%);

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to fix via CSS the line-height equals to your container height

in your case, if you want to keep all your work, you can change margin-top of elements

```
#nav-links a {
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #CC020C;
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```